# Merge [mac] and [osx], making [mac] a synonym of [osx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We have the [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag without any wiki and 127 questions and the [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag with a wiki and 367 questions (and the synonym [apple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple)). IMHO we don't need *both* tags (I don't see anybody discussing e.g. problems with TeXLive on Linux on Apple systems).

Proposal: Make [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) a synoym of [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx).

Comment: But what about all our Apple II users? ;)

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Show me a TeX installation on an Apple ][. :-)

Comment: Are any of the existing questions about Mac OS as opposed to Mac OS X?

Comment: @cfr: I doubt that - they would be ancient. Mac OS 9.2.2 was released in 2002.

Comment: An awful lot of places were still using Mac OS years later, though, because lots of places had software which had not been ported or substituted for OS X. Possibly, however, those people were not using TeX or not having problems with it, if they were. (I would not be terribly surprised if people are still running it in certain cases, in fact.)

Comment: I once had a PowerPC mac that was running Linux ... kinda miss those days.  –--  But as a current osx on mac user I think the merger would make sense.

Comment: @cfr Even if we had any OSnotX questions, would it mean we need to distinguish it by a separate tag that nobody's gonna use correctly?

Comment: @yo' If we had any Mac OS questions then, yes, we'd need to distinguish them. At least, the case for doing so would be considerably stronger than that for distinguishing Mac OS X from other BSD questions or, even, from GNU/Linux questions since those systems are much more similar than Mac OS and Mac OS X. Whether people would use it correctly is another matter, but they would hardly be the only tags nobody uses correctly. However, if we don't have any such questions, the issue is irrelevant.

Comment: @jan I still have a PPC which dual boots Debian and OS X. I believe it can also emulate Mac OS for software purposes, but it can't boot Mac OS or run in Mac OS mode operating-system wise.

Comment: What about the change in name that's gonna happen from Sierra onwards? It should still be technically `OS 10`, but `Mac OS X` will be replaced by "macOS" to fit the naming scheme of other Apple devices and platforms.

Comment: @JosephWright: Would the moderators please decide about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've merged the tags here, leaving [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) as the 'master' (as noted, MacOS X is being replaced by Apple by 'macOS').

Answer (score 0):

To help people find tags with a few letters, I feel some interest in hyphenated tags. And to avoid tag recreation, would something like [apple-mac-osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-mac-osx) suit your needs?

Comment: Ummmm no. You've got tag synonyms for this; the fulltext tag selection recognizes the master tag itself and all its synonyms.