# Request to rename [mac] → [macos], with synonym of [osx]

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

The current name of Apple's desktop operating system is [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS). On this site, the tag [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) is used to refer to that.

But other Stack Exchange sites use the tag [macos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), including:

- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) (Apple)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) (Gaming)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)

So I would like to request that we rename [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) → [macos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), thus making us consistent with the other sites. We can keep the former tag as a synonym.

Additionally, we should have [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) (the operating system was formerly called "OS X") as a synonym, as previously discussed at [Merge [mac] and [osx], making [mac] a synonym of [osx]](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6876/189731)

Comment: IMO this is a nice proposal. I should mention that the `osx` synonym is already available in the main-site

Comment: The difference between `macros` and `macos` is pretty small and the tags are displayed pretty small. I don't like the proposal therefore.

Comment: I concur with @skillmon.

Comment: @Skillmon [Stack Overflow also has a `macros` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros). Same with [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros). If they are able to make both `macros` and `macos` tags work, I don't see why this site should be any different.

Comment: macros, being the fundamental programming paradigm used in tex, the macros tag is likely more important here and the possibility of confusion greater.  Are there many occasions that you move from one site to the other and get confused by the tag names being different?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, yes. I am more frequently on other Stack Exchange sites and joined this one when I started dabbling in LaTeX. It was confusing to me that this site used a different tag for macOS than all the others.

Comment: @Skillmon the tag [`macos`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) is already used so the "confusion" is already here.

Comment: How about [tag:mac-os]?  I'm definitely in favour of merging all macOS related tags into one.

Comment: @HenriMenke That still has the problem of not matching other sites. Besides, if we kept `macos` as a synonym that redirects to `mac-os`, then we'd still have confusion anyway.

Comment: @PaulGaborit - There are only 44 `macos`-tagged postings on TeX.SE, 482 `mactex`-tagged postings, and a whopping 5752 `macros`-tagged queries. Changing the tag of the `mac` postings to `macos` would increase the number of `macos`-tagged queries by a factor of more than 10 -- and thus quite likely cause actual confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Let's take a look at the numbers of postings with various Mac-related tags:

```
mac       559
macos      44
mactex    482
texshop   495 % a Mac-only front end
latexian   13 % another Mac-only front end

macros   5752 % "macros" is among the "top ten" of all tags on TeX.SE
```

The majority of the 44 `macos`-tagged postings is not actually related to MacOS (the operating system) in a meaningful way. If anything, many of these postings should be re-tagged as either `mac` or `mactex`. However, there *is* a handful of `macos`-tagged postings with a clear link to MacOS, so I wouldn't get rid of the `macos` tag entirely -- or make it into a synonym for `mac`.

I can see no justification for re-tagging all 559 `mac`-tagged postings as `macos`. The focus of the overwhelming majority of the `mac`-tagged postings is clearly the Mac ecosystem, *not* the MacOS operating system (a small subset of the Mac ecosystem). One can easily verify that some of the `mac`-tagged postings are not acually all clearly related to any part of the Mac ecosystem and hence that the `mac` tag isn't appropriate for them. However, the fact that the postings are tagged incorrectly cannot be a reason for adopting the `macos` tag for them.

I would certainly not advocate changing the tag of `mactex` postings to `macos`.

There are also some postings tagged with `texworks`, a multi-platform front-end, and some of these postings are from users who use `texworks` on a Mac. However, the focus of these postings is on `texworks`, and it would be an error to change their tags to `mac`, let alone `macos`.

Another thought: Currently, postings tagged with `macros` outnumber those tagged with `macos` by a factor of more than one hundred to one. Since we should care about not creating unnecessary confusion, and because `macos` and `macros` do look rather alike at first glance, increasing the number of  `macos`-tagged postings by a factor of more than 10 could very well be rather counterproductive.

Comment: +1: Please stay, seriously!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - OK, you, egreg, and others have convinced me. :-) I will take some time off, though, to recharge my batteries, so to say.

Comment: That's really good news!